# jQuery: css z-index not working

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I'm trying to make my table to show on the top of the overlay class. So far so bad. Please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/u96coj0q/

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
</table>
<button>Overlay</button>

table {
    background-color: white;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 50;
}

$('button').click(function() {
        $('body').append("<div class='overlay'></div>");
        $('table').css('zIndex', '60');
        $('table').css({ zIndex: 60 });
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For `z-index` to work, add `position: relative` or `position: absolute;` [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u96coj0q/4/)

```
table {
    position: relative; 
    background-color: white;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

you can just add `$('table').css({ 'position': 'relative' });` to the click event

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('body').append("<div class='overlay'></div>");
    $('table').css('zIndex', '60');
    $('table').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
});
```

Comment: Why not adding the `position` directly in CSS as it should be? You know, all this JS can be in CSS and the only requirement to display the overlay would be to add another class to `.overlay`. ;)

Comment: that is just another alternative way, in case you cannot edit the css file or the HTML file

Answer (score 0):

Add `position` property to `table`. I guess in your case you need `position: relative;`.

`z-index` will never work if the element does not have a `position` property set up.

```
table {
    position: relative; /* this is required for z-index */
    background-color: white;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Here is a working jsfidle: http://jsfiddle.net/Smartik/u96coj0q/3/

---

Here is another example that will minimize the JS and make use more of CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/Smartik/u96coj0q/5/

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create a class or classes and call them with .addClass() or .toggleClass()

```
.zindex60 {z-index:60;}

$('button').click(function() {
   $('body').append("<div class='overlay'></div>");
   $('table').addClass('zindex60');
});
```